# Is it possible to save selected data “columns” in Windows folders?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

Currently when I open a folder in windows it uses some default columns of data. I can modify this but it never seems to "stick". How can I make these alternate data columns permanent, or better yet permanent to a specific folder?

For example, in a folder of sound assets I'd like to sort it by Date Modified and remove all the Artist/Album/Etc stuff. Every time I open this folder I have to do this over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has the concept of folder templates, there are five different templates for different types of folders:

- General Items
- Documents
- Pictures
- Music
- Videos

On the `customize` tab of the properties window you can specify which template should be used for a folder.

You can configure the columns, order, view etc for each of the templates.

An [article on How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/) describes how to do this.